# grep for string and open matching files in text editor

Tags: grep, pipe, xargs

I wasn't able to find an answer for this simple question. I had a solution for it years ago and I think it involved something like **{ }**, but I've totally forgotten now.

I'm looking to grep for a pattern in all files in a directory and open them in a text editor. I tend to use **nedit** and **subl**.

```
grep -il "gating" *
```

will find matching files, but I can't seem to send those matching filenames as arguments to open an editor.

```
grep -il "gating" * | xargs subl
```

either complains that the program doesn't exist or it opens up some random stuff.

```
subl file1 file2 file3
```

will open all 3 files in the same editor window. Doing this with grep would be ideal. I thought maybe piping it would work, but grasp of shell commands is limited, at best.

Comment: Try: `subl $(grep -il "gating" *)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I just get an "Illegal variable name." output.

Answer (score 1):

With utilities that have nonstandard null options, you could try something like:

```
grep -Zil "gating" * | xargs -0 subl
```

However, if the command run by `xargs` needs input from a terminal, something more complicated may be needed.

A more general approach could be to use `find` instead of `xargs`:

```
find * -exec grep -qi "gating" {} \; -exec subl {} +
```

This runs `grep` on each file in turn (I assume `*` doesn't select directories), and if it finds a match, the filename is appended to the `subl` command. There is no pipeline, so stdin for the final command remains the terminal.

`subl` will be invoked with batches of files (as many each time as will fit in the maximum allowed length of a command - Cf. `xargs`'s `-s` option).